# Multiple states from the same activity in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, state

It is possible to save multiple different user-interface states (that means, written text in the editText, selected options in radio buttons, etc.) from the same activity and, later (after an onDestroy()), select one of them to recover the activity state?

Comment: so, you want to save all the state on destory of that activity and use in later case.??

Comment: Yes, I want to save multiple different states of the same activity (in multiple executiosn of the application) and later select one of them.

Comment: then use application class for that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use SharedPreferences to persist your Activity state